# PDF3D - How to extract mesh colors and change buttons background fillColor

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm currently working on a script to extract the mesh material color and replace this value to the fillColor attribute of some buttons.

This is the script that runs when a button is pressed:

```
var c3d = this.getAnnots3D(this.pageNum)[0].context3D;

function printObjectsNames() {
    for (var i=0; i < c3d.scene.meshes.count; i++) {

        //Creates an array of the 3D meshes in the scene
        var array = c3d.scene.meshes.getByIndex(i);

        //Extract the mesh name and populate some Text Fields  
        this.getField("Mesh "+(i+1)).value = array.name;

        //Extract the mesh material color and replace
        //some buttons background color
        ???????

        //Print some values in the console
        console.println("Object: "+array);
        console.println("Object name: "+array.name);
        console.println("Diffuse Color: "+array.material.diffuseColor);
     }
}

printObjectsNames();
```

As expected when I run the command the console shows this

```
Object: [object Mesh]
Object name: STK1000
Diffuse Color: Color: ( 0, 1, 1 )
Object: [object Mesh]
Object name: LUCIDO
Diffuse Color: Color: ( 1, 0, 1 )
Object: [object Mesh]
Object name: STRUTTURA
Diffuse Color: Color: ( 0.7451, 0.7451, 0.7451 )
```

The 3 meshes have different `diffuseColor`

The problem is that I can't put the value `diffuseColor` in the background color attribute because the `array.material.diffuseColor` extracts

`Color: ( 0, 1, 1 )` and not only `( 0, 1, 1 )`

How can I extract only the `( 0, 1, 1 )` value?

Thank you very much for the help,

Julio

Comment: Please don't write solved with the answer. Once you have enough rep you can answer you own questions. Until then refrain from doing this. Rather than leave this hanging i'll add a wiki answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>OPs own answer to problem:</sub>

This is the solution to put inside the for loop:

```
 var objColor = array.material.diffuseColor
var r = objColor.r
var g = objColor.g
var b = objColor.b

this.getField("foo").fillColor = [ "RGB", r, g, b ];
```